# AngularJS and control identification

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and can't seem to break through the ice on how to see the difference between which objects are being changed. This snippit of code show 3 knob-controllers dynamically being created based on the list **sensors**:

```
            var sensors = ['light','audio','o2'];
            for (sensor_idx in sensors) {
                var sensor = sensors[sensor_idx];
                $(".knobs-row").append(
                    $('<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 centered">' +
                    '   <center>' +
                    '       <h2>' + sensor + '</h2>' +
                    '       <div ng-controller="' + sensor + '-knobCtrl">' +
                    '           <ui-knob  value="value" options="options"></ui-knob>' +
                    '       </div>' +
                    '   </center>' +
                    '</div>') )

                app.controller(sensor + '-knobCtrl', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.value = 65;
                    $scope.options = {
                        barWidth: 40,
                        size: 300,
                    };
                    $scope.$watch( "value", function(n,o,s) { do_something_dependent_on_sensor_type() }, true);
                });
            }
```

How do I know which sensor knob-controller has changed?

Br Jakob

Comment: this isn't proper syntax for angular.  Don't append HTML to the DOM like this, use `ng-repeat` instead. Also, don't use a controller per table row, use a single controller for the entire view content.

Comment: How does this help me? If I use ng-repeat how do I get n controls that I can differ between on a name or ID level?

Comment: I just worked up a quick sample using `ng-repeat`, is this something like what you are expecting to do? http://plnkr.co/edit/Oi1BKD2tlm7EnL7SzUll?p=preview

Comment: I think it's close. I need to call a function with access to the changed value and the sensor name.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of that ng-knob module (it has a few missing implementations) but the sample I provided should show how it's used;  since it doesn't support `ng-change`, you will still have to rely on `$scope.$watch`, but you can watch each object in the array easily enough.

Comment: All I get when I watch the value is the value. I have no idea which of the knobs that are changing.

Comment: it would be much easier if this particular module supported `ng-change` and `ng-model`;  right now, the `ng-knob` model doesn't have any mechanism at all to identify what it changed (it doesn't understand the concept of anything but `value`).  The only way I can think is to watch the array, and compare the old and new values of each array element each time the array changes.

Comment: something like http://plnkr.co/edit/Oi1BKD2tlm7EnL7SzUll?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Claies! It seems to do the job. Too bad that knob is the nicest of the dialers out there when it's incomplete :-)

Comment: their documentation for it is very weird; as I look at it, I don't know that the designers of that module have a complete understanding of the angular life cycle;  there are quite a few things that could be improved with it's design.